# Open an iOS page/screen in flutter plugin using native components

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am able to successfully create the Android version of a Flutter plugin to launch an Activity with the custom Java/Android code, including the View part using methods like onAttachedToActivity, onDetachedFromActivity, onAttachedToEngine etc.
Now, I also need the iOS version of that plugin. I am not an iOS developer but my first step is to open/integrate the "Hello world" Storyboard type Xcode project using Flutter plugin.
Below is the plugin code, can you provide me with an example of how I can open the native iOS UI view from this plugin code?

```
import UIKit

public class SwiftPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "swift_plugin_channel", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
  }
}
```